# download file/backup from remote server to desktop without SSH or SCP?

Tags: php, scp, openssl

**Issue Background**

I was trying to install uTorrent on my PHP site and mid-process I was kicked out of SSH and the website went down.

libssl.so.1.0.0 and libcrypto.so.1.0.0 were required for uTorrent so to downgrade, I did the following:

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.0r.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.0r
./config shared && make
```

I then got an error saying "No version could be found for libssl.so.1.0.0 and libcrypto.so.1.0.0". I proceeded to delete both of them from my server hoping to revert the changes and it was when I got kicked out of SSH and the site went down.

Now I can't connect via SSH, only way is via KVM provided by my host.

**Question**

I'm trying to get the error logs and backup files from the server via SCP. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
scp: error while loading shared libraries: /lib64/libcrypto.so.10 file too short
```

How can I download the files now?